# how to give a default value to ag-grid filter

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Trying to display a default value in ag-grid filter text . In filter param I want to give a default value to be displayed to user not only to be applied on the result

```
this.columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: this.pageData["tbm.line.list.grid.phonenumber"],
    field: 'tn',
    /*sort: "asc",*/
    sortable: true,
    filter: "agTextColumnFilter",
    filterParams: { filterOptions: ['contains'], apply: true },
    //tooltip: (params) => 'Address: ' + params.value,
    headerTooltip: 'Phone Number',
    // editable: true,
    // checkboxSelection: true,
    // headerCheckboxSelection: true,
    // headerCheckboxSelectionFilteredOnly: true,
    width: 150
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set a default value on you filter, you can make use of the `firstDataRendered` event, and set the initial filter model.

```
<ag-grid-angular
  #agGrid
  style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
  id="myGrid"
  class="ag-theme-balham"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
  [rowData]="rowData"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
  (firstDataRendered)="onFirstDataRendered($event)"
></ag-grid-angular>
```

And on your component.ts,

```
onFirstDataRendered() {
  const yourFilterComponent = this.gridApi.getFilterInstance('athlete');
  yourFilterComponent.setModel({
    type: 'contains',
    filter: 'Phelps'
  });
  this.gridApi.onFilterChanged();
}
```

I have created a demo over [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/yueIduPRK07APY0zj8ji?p=preview).

Comment: Both answers here do work but it is not a clean solution as it makes 2 api requests one initial without the filter and one with the filter. So far I have not found a solution which does a singe api request without canceling the first manually.

Answer (score 2):

A little change in above answer worked for me. In .ts instead setModel() i have uses **setFilterModel** for apiGrid.

```
<ag-grid-angular
  #agGrid
  style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
  id="myGrid"
  class="ag-theme-balham"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
  [rowData]="rowData"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
  (firstDataRendered)="onFirstDataRendered($event)"
></ag-grid-angular>
```

And on your component.ts,

```
onFirstDataRendered() {
  this.gridApi.setFilterModel({
  "year": {
    filterType: 'set',
    values: ["2010"],
  }
})
  this.gridApi.onFilterChanged();
}
```